# adhere another handler on click function after event

Tags: jquery, html

i have a `<div>` as button in my body which fires an event with jQuery's `click`

```
<div id="pause"><img id="pausebtn" src="pause.png" /></div>
```

and binded an eventhandler to this button

```
$('#pause').bind('click', btnHandler);

function btnHandler() { /* something incredible happens here*/ }
```

what i would like to do is, that after the first `click`of `#pause`the handler changes to another function, lets say to

```
$('#pause').bind('click', btnHandler2);
```

any help would be much appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to register a event handler which will run only once

```
$('#pause').one('click', btnHandler);

function btnHandler() {
     $(this).on('click',btnHandler2);
}
```

Comment: @roasted I think the OPs comment is for you

Comment: @supersize no, no absolutely not sarcastic

Answer (score 2):

you will want to `unbind` the event handler and `bind` a new one.

Note on `bind()` and `unbind()` methods:
[As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
function btnHandler() {
  // unbind old event - supply the handler here so nothing else gets unbound
  $('#pause').off('click',btnHandler);
  // rebind new event
  $('#pause').on('click',btnHandler2);
}

$('#pause').on('click',btnHandler);
```

The difference between `.bind()` and `.on()` lies in the ability to create delegated events using the `.on()` method. A delegated event is bound to your "targets" parent, which has to exist when the event is bound. By supplying a descendant-selector you can then have this event triggered for all elements that are contained in said parent and match the given selector

Example:

```
// this will be triggered for any element with class 'bla' 
// inside the body tag, no matter when said element was added.
$('body').on('click','.bla',console.log);
```

Comment: didnt know that. whats the basic difference between `bind`and `on` and why its deprecated?

Comment: +1 but bind/unbind are not deprecated, just on/off are preferred. Maybe early stage before being deprecated

Comment: @supersize this is for consitency with event delegation. BTW, its preferred to use 'on' syntax because some customized jquery could have removed events alias

Comment: not sure why i thought they were deprecated, i updated my answer. :)

Comment: @supersize Right now the only difference between `bind` and `on` is that `bind` is an additional function call, since internally jQuery just calls `on` with the relevant arguments when your code calls `bind`. I think the main focus was having a *single* function that handled all of your event handling needs rather than having to use a combination of `bind` and `delegate` depending on the situation; there were also no doubt performance improvements, but older code using `bind` and `delegate` is still going to (largely) benefit from those as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this inside your first event handler:

```
function btnHandler(event) {
    $(this).unbind();
    $(this).bind('click', btnHandler2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can unbind the event in the function..i.e.

```
function btnHandler(event){
    //your code
    $(this).unbind(event);
    $('#pause').bind('click', btnHandler2);
}
```